# How to get a circular image in iOS ScrollView?

Tags: swift, user-interface, swift4

I am attempting to produce a circular image in ScrollView. Although, my image is always appearing to be widened (not a circle) no matter what I change the constraints to be.

Here is my scrollview and its image in its current state:

[image]

I am trying to have the image be displayed as a circle rather than a flattened one. My end goal is to have my scrollview's image appear in this manner:

[image]

Here is my code that generates my scroll view

```swift
func setUpScrollView(){
        view.addSubview(profileImageView)

        scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true

        createDatePicker()
        createToolBar()

        //Image Picker
        scrollView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        profileImageView.anchor(top: scrollView.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 60, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 32)

        scrollView.addSubview(imagePickerLabel)
        imagePickerLabel.anchor(top: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 50)

        //      Birthday Picker
        scrollView.addSubview(dateOfBirthContainer)
        dateOfBirthContainer.anchor(top: imagePickerLabel.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 50)
        dateOfBirthTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        //Gender Picker
        scrollView.addSubview(genderContainer)
        genderContainer.anchor(top: dateOfBirthContainer.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 50)
        genderTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

        //University Picker
        scrollView.addSubview(universityContainer)
        universityContainer.anchor(top: genderContainer.bottomAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: view.rightAnchor, paddingTop: 16, paddingLeft: 32, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 32, width: 0, height: 50)
        universityTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    }
}
```

And here is the code that attempts to make the ImageView a circle

```swift
var profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(openImagePicker))
        let iv = UIImageView()
        iv.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        iv.addGestureRecognizer(imageTap)
        iv.image =  UIImage(named: "small-avatar")
        iv.layer.borderWidth = 1
        iv.layer.masksToBounds = false
        iv.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor as! CGColor
        iv.layer.cornerRadius = 125//This will change with corners of image and height/2 will make this circle shape
        iv.clipsToBounds = true
        return iv
    }()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by `Sh_khan` your `imageView` is not anchored to reflect a width and height for the `imageView` that is why your `imageView` is collapsed because you didn't define how it is represented on the screen.
As a rule of thumb you always need to define 4 things, width and height, x position and y position and you can do that with constraints. 
here is an example how I would define that.

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor),
imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.CenterXAnchor), 
])
```

Comment: Thank you so much  this along with @abatjarg comment worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

You either need

```
iv.layer.cornerRadius = 16 /// 32/2
```

OR

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
   super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
     profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = profileImageView.frame.height / 2.0
 }
```

Note for circular image you need to make sure that width = height for the imageView , currently you set left , top , right and height , while you should set top , centerX , width and height

Comment: Can you please expand more as to how i should set the top , centerX , width and height constraints? I am a noob to this aspect of swift

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints in your imageview since you are using programmatic autolayout. Try setting that to false in your imageview.

Comment: Thank you, I have been testing out so many different solutions that I forgot to set this property.